# Parenthesis after field name in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I always work in C#, but I've been asked to work on a legacy VB.Net solution. In the legacy code, I am seeing this:

```
Private transactionListField() As TransactionInfoForStatement
```

This makes no sense to me! If it was C#, I'd expect this:

```
private List<Transaction> _transactions;
```

Can someone please explain to me what that VB code does? The parenthesis after the name makes me think it is calling a method, but when I `Go To Definition` in Visual Studio, I just end up on the same line!

Comment: From auto-converter... it means: `private TransactionInfoForStatement[] transactionListField`

Comment: It isn't a List, it is an Array.

Comment: @DanielShillcock that's why naming is so important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's an [array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/) declaration, you could also use this syntax that i prefer:

```
TransactionListField As TransactionInfoForStatement() ' array which is declared but Nothing
```

Arrays or indexers always use `()` in VB.NET as opposed to C# where you use `[]`.

There's one advantage if you use the braces-first-syntax, you can specify the size:

```
TransactionListField(10) As TransactionInfoForStatement ' array that contains 11 Nothing
```